# Create an useful and scalable class for SQLite Android

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I developing a new android application and I want create a new class to manage SQLite, but I want know the best practice for this.

So, I have three or more resources in my project: `rss`,`fb`,`tweet` and in future more resources.. Every resources have five method like `getItems()` , `getFeed()` , `insert()`, `delete()` and etc..

My actual class for db manager have a singleton and I know that this is not a good practice. I don't want create a God class with all method for accessing to database. :(

How can I setup my new class? Can I have a piece of pseudocode for learning it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may consider [ORMLite for android](http://ormlite.com/sqlite_java_android_orm.shtml). It provides all your needs with powerful DAOs classes: insert, update, delete. 
ORMLite's features:

- Setup your classes by simply adding Java annotations.
- Powerful abstract Database Access Object (DAO) classes.
- Flexible QueryBuilder to easily construct simple and complex queries.
- Supports MySQL, Postgres, Microsoft SQL Server, H2, Derby, HSQLDB, and Sqlite and can be extended to additional databases relatively easily.
- Provisional support for DB2, Oracle, ODBC, and Netezza. Contact the author if your database type is not supported.
- Handles "compiled" SQL statements for repetitive query tasks.
- Supports "foreign" objects with the class field being the object but an id stored in the database table.
- Basic support for database transactions.
- Auto generates SQL to create and drop database tables.
- Spring configuration support for DOAs and class configurations.
- Support for configuring of tables and fields without annotations.

[Here](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/doc-files/ormlite_1.html#Getting-Started) is the place where you can get start

Answer (score 1):

Make **interface** class and put them on it " `getItems() , getFeed() , insert(), delete()` "
and then **implements** other classed on the interface class.